# Server Sent Events + Asp Core, why I can't make it work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, server-sent-events

I am trying SSE just to see how they work but I can't understand why this code is not working. I am getting a client error.
In my asp controller:

```
public class Example {
    public Example() {
        X = "12";
        Y = 5;
    }

    public string X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}

public async Task Messaggio() {
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    var msg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Example());
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    Response.Body.Close();
}
```

Client-side generated html:

```
<html><head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

ciaoooo
<div id="Messaggio"></div>

<script>
    source = new EventSource('/Home/Messaggio');
    source.onopen = function (ddd) {
        console.log("aperta");
    };
    source.onerror = function (ddd) {
        console.log("errore");
        console.log(ddd.data);
        source.close();
    };

    source.onmessage = function (ddd) {
        $("#Messaggio").text(ddd.data);
        console.log(ddd.data);
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Browser console output:

```
aperta
errore
undefined
```

routes are ok because if I request /home/messaggio it does work, I get the Json file

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add the **"data"** attribute before the returned "msg", so you cannot get the `ddd.data` value in js.

Modify the `Messaggio` action as follows:

```
 public async Task Messaggio()
    { 
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
        var msg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Example());
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"data: {msg}\n\n");
        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        Response.Body.Close(); 
    }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasted so much time on this